# nodemon постоянный restarting

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

При запуске json.js nodemon постоянно обновляется "restarting due to changes", хотя никаких изменений в файл я не вношу. Вот собственно json.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");

var originalNote = {
  title: "Some title",
  body: "Some body"
};
var originalNoteString = JSON.stringify(originalNote);
fs.writeFileSync("notes.json", originalNoteString);

var noteString = fs.readFileSync("notes.json");
var note = JSON.parse(noteString);
console.log(typeof note);
console.log(note.title);
```

Comment: В package.json пропишите `"nodemonConfig": { "ignore": ["*.json"] }` чтобы не отслеживались изменения в json-файлах.

Comment: Спасибо, все понял!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя `json.js` при каждом запуске пишет что-то в файл `notes.json` и так по кругу.

> nodemon will watch **the files in the directory in which nodemon** was
>   started, and if any files change, nodemon will automatically restart
>   your node application.

Т.е. он реагирует не только на изменение `json.js`. Он проверяет изменение всех файлов в директории.

Comment: Надо уточнить, что nodemon следит за этим файлом, и при его изменении перезапускает скрипт

Comment: Большое спасибо!